# Autolayout not placing Google Sign in Button as Expected

Tags: ios, google-plus, autolayout

I am `iOS` beginner and trying to learn by doing a project. I need to add a `Google +` Sign in button in the middle of the screen. Here is how my autolayout constraints look like

[image]
and

[image]
and when I run this, I see the following

[image]
and
[image]

**Question**
How can I make sure the my view comes in middle as I add constraints? What settings I am missing and need to learn?

Thanks

**UPDATE 01**
As per @Dean's suggestion, I made the change as

[image]

But when I run this, I still see it as

[image]

Could it be because of image size? How do I know about it?

**UPDATE 02**
After resolving all the autolayout issues, I see the following
[image]

Comment: Your Google + image is bigger in length then the specified length of given button.

Comment: Remove the right constraint and add a constraint for the middle of the button to the middle of the superview.

Comment: @dasdom, can you please explain "add a constraint for the middle of the button to the middle of the superview"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to select the button and delete all the restraints that you have.

Go to the Editor menu. Select Align and then Horizontal Center In Container and Vertical Center in Container. That is all the constraints you want on the button.

[image: XCode Editor Menu Image]

Given that we have established your constraints are now correct. It would appear that your button, coming from Google, is initially reporting its maximum width as its width property. Once you set the style and the image is loaded, the actual width is determined by the resulting localized message string.

I would place `[self.view setNeedsLayout]` and `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` somewhere after all processing is complete. This will likely obtain the correct width and adjust layout centered as desired.

If you are programmatically adding the button in your view class implementation, as in the example you followed to manually set the frame, and still want to use autolayout try this code in place of the code you copied from photohunt:

```
      GPPSignInButton *signInButton = [[GPPSignInButton alloc] init];
      [signInButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
      [signInButton setStyle:kGPPSignInButtonStyleWide];
      [signInButton setColorScheme:kGPPSignInButtonColorSchemeLight];
       NSLayoutConstraint *vConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:signInButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0];
       NSLayoutConstraint *hConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:signInButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0];
       [self.view addConstraint:vConstraint];
       [self.view addConstraint:hConstraint];

       [self.view addSubview:signInButton];
```

I cannot test it, but as the constraints are now added after the button is initialized I am betting it gets the layout correct.

Comment: Thanks @Dean, I just updated my question based on your answer

Comment: To start with, you should go back to that Editor menu, select Resolve Auto Layout Issues --> Update All Frames In View. The dotted frames are showing that you have some kind of conflict. This will update your IB window to reflect the true result. Look at all the constraints and make sure the centering constraints are the only existing.

Comment: Thanks,  I just updated my answer, may be I am missing something again

Comment: Click on the horizontal restraint and check the constant setting in the inspector. Is it zero?

Comment: I see the constraints now working properly in preview. It has to have something to do with the button and/or the image. It would seem that the image is wider than it looks. Is there some white or clear space to the left of the red rectangle? Check the image itself as it sets the button width.

Comment: About the only other thing I can think of is the edge insets settings of the button. If you have altered those, that could effect the appearance in relation to the actual size.

Comment: http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/08/google-sign-in-localisation.html I am using `kGPPSignInButtonStyleWide`

Comment: If you have been messing with these settings to debug, I would suggest deleting the button. Create a new fresh default instance, add only two constraints. Set the image. If it still shows offset, it has to be the image wider than it looks.

Comment: Not familiar with that, let me look at your link.

Comment: Try StyleStandard. It looks to me that the image is telling the button its max width, but displays differently depending on the language. Ultimately, your choice would seem to be inspecting the actual size on load, then correcting the layout as required. Or it may be just a matter of refreshing layouts after loading the image. I am not sure without getting into a mock project to experiment.

Comment: If there is a callback or some way of knowing when that image is finished loading, try 'self.view setNeedsLayout'. It may be as simple as that. As a check, I would throw that somewhere arbitrarily as late in the presentation process as possible or with a timer to delay. If that works, then you know where to go with it for sure.

Comment: The programmatic way worked for me. Thanks a ton @Dean

Answer (score -2):

I found the issue, the following fixed it

```
CGFloat x = roundf((320.0 - signInButton.frame.size.width) / 2.0);
  CGFloat y = roundf((80.0 - signInButton.frame.size.height) / 2.0);
  [signInButton setFrame:CGRectMake(x,
                                    y,
                                    signInButton.frame.size.width,
                                    signInButton.frame.size.height)];
  [self addSubview:signInButton];
```

After much googling around I found a sample `iOS` application by google developers and it is mentioned https://developers.google.com/+/photohunt/ios#displaying_the_sign-in_button

As per them

> Also, the button can stretch across almost the whole width, so the
>   wide button style is used

After this, I saw that the button was centered

[image]

The problem now is that it is located at the top of the page, but that's a separate issue to deal with :)

**UPDATE**
Thanks @Fogmeister and @Dean. As per @Dean's suggestion, I made the change for `x` and `y` as

```
CGFloat x = roundf((float) ((self.view.bounds.size.width - signInButton.frame.size.width) / 2.0));
CGFloat y = roundf((float) ((self.view.bounds.size.height - signInButton.frame.size.height) / 2.0));
```

and it landed up perfectly in portrait mode
[image]
However, in landscape mode, this still doesn't line up very well
[image]

Any ideas? (Now I am not hardcoding values that should break Autolayout)

Comment: This will absolutely break AutoLayout. You cannot use `setFrame`, `setBounds` or `setCenter` when using AutoLayout. What you have done here is just calculate the centre rect and set it. This isn't using AutoLayotu at all.

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at the Ray Wenderlich - Beginning Auto Layout tutorial. It will introduce you to the basics of AutoLayout. The problem in this question is a very basic thing that AutoLayout is perfect for fixing.

Comment: That would be fine if you were not using Autolayout. You can easily adjust your calculations to center the button (exchange 320 for self.view.bounds.size.width and the 80 for bounds.height), however, arguably this is not the best solution. If you are mixing autolayout with these methods, you are bound for trouble.

Comment: Just tried and updated with what you guys suggested, works well in Portrait mode but not in landscape

Comment: That is exactly what autolayout is built for. If you are manually setting the frame, you will have to do it every time the layout changes. In that case you would have to reset the frame when the device is rotated. Try the alternate method that I added to my answer. Using that method of creating the button should result in correct layout automatically on all changes, all devices and all orientations.

Comment: Understand that you are still "hard coding" the position of the button and circumventing the autolayout process. In this case, you are calculating the position at the time of initialization. The button will be stuck with those values until you change them. Autolayout solves this by reevaluating and calculating the new frame location whenever the layout of the view changes.

Comment: Alternate method? "If there is a callback or some way of knowing when that image is finished loading, try 'self.view setNeedsLayout'." Do I not create the button in `XIB` and rather programmatically?

Comment: I added code, modifying what you took from photohunt. Should be easy cut and paste replacement to allow inserting the button in code while still using autolayout to manage the placement. Not tested, but I believe it will work.

Comment: throws exception `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: Constraint items must each be an instance of UIView or subclass'`

Comment: That would be on account of I am not familiar with your hierarchy. Is your class a subclass of UIView or UIViewController? If controller, change self in the constraint to self.view.

Comment: `@interface GooglePlusLoginViewController : UIViewController <GPPSignInDelegate>`

Comment: I just validated, It worked out really well. I really need to learn from you about resources to learn about `    NSLayoutConstraint *vConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:signInButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *hConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:signInButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0];
`

Comment: @daydreamer Ray Wenderlich. There is an awesome Auto Layout tutorial. Google it.